# rails model.blank? returns false even though I purged the db

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model of Journey. To refresh the db, I called the following

```
rake db:reset db:migrate
```

which should purge the database of all existing data and restart the database.

I called `Journey.first` in my console, which returns nil as expected.

But why is it that when I called `Journey.blank?` it returns `false`? Is the database not empty (or blank) at this point?

If not, how can I check to see if my Journey model is empty or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check to see if there are no elements in the database, not if the object [is actually blank](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F).

For that, just make a count query instead.

```
Journey.count # should return 0
```